# build or buy buck converter

Tags: buck, converter, step-down

Hi I am looking to step down a 10 volt DC to 5 DC with low output current (less then 1 amp)
Is it the best to build a buck converter or to buy it ready ?
thank you

---

Actually I am using an arduino, 
I am not sure if using the 5 volt of the arduino is recommended ?
my circuit involve 4 L293D that requires 5 volt,
I have 10 volt available that I can step down to 5 volt,
This circuit is a design so will always be under power
I saw that a buck converter does not generate too much heat which is good for a circuit always power on

Comment: Best by what criteria?

Comment: It is easier to buy one, could be cheaper to design one. For a one off then get one.

Comment: *Assuming best means cheap and easy* Look for an LM2596 based module, they're less than $ 2 including shipping. You **cannot beat the price** by buying the components separately and you will also you need a PCB. In a module all is included. Only if you want many (thousands) of these will making your own be cheaper and even then it will be a lot of work. Also: a module will **just work**.

Comment: if best means cheap and reliable, BUY.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what it is for.

If you are making yourself a one-time, or few-times, gizmo for a dedicated function buying an off-the shelf convertor is your best, and usually cheapest, bet. Though you may want to buy a few spares.

However, if you are designing a product, integrating a design is usually a safer approach. Using someone else's product puts you at the mercy of their standards and availability, both immediate, and long term. There is nothing worse than completing a year long design and qualification cycle, only to find out that the OEM part is no longer available, or has been changed.

Further, the assumption that the drop in part will "just work" is not always the case. With some, the "just" part has more emphasis than the "work" part.

There are numerous dubious suppliers out there. It is prudent to do your due diligence and find alternative suppliers, purchase samples, and compare them for compliance with what you expect them to do in the environments you expect them to handle.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely buy, you can buy [78XX series drop](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/power-supplies-board-mount/dc-dc-converters/922?k=7805) in compatible DC to DC converters. They are easy to use and you only have to design the footprint for one component.

Comment: all right I will give try with V78W-500 to convert 9 volt to 5 volt; is the component going to generate too much heat if always powered on ?

Comment: The efficiency usually runs 85 to 95% (depending on the voltage) so its really good, as good as most step downs. If you like the answer upvote